# Blender Texturing Problem, cant figure it out

Tags: texturing

im trying to get this work now since almost 1 week and i cant, im watching serveral Videos etc.. nothing can help me (beside this, there is no video for something like this , at least i couldnt find any),

so now i try to get help,

i got this Wall on the Right, i try to Copy it to learn, i got all the Textures the Person used for it but i still cant get it work, nothing fits together, im cluesless tbh.

(Im a hobby Coder and now since a certain time im trying to get 3D Art done and no its not easy but im putting so much time in it and it doest work out :S)

[image]

[image: Clueless]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a texture coordinate node and a mapping node.

It might be wise to use a Principled BDSF also.

I couldn't check if it was correct because the images were not packed into the blend file but this was the first thing I saw.

Also in your Diffuse Shader, there is a normal input where your normal map goes if you still prefer to use a Diffuse Colour node.
Purple coloured slots use vector information.
Gray coloured slots are for black and white images/info. So the displacement slot on the material output is only really good for grayscale Displacement maps.

[image]

Let me know if that works for you now :)